# Is it possible to print an iterated range of arguments via cli from a csv? (see example)

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, csv

I have hundreds of logs spread across a few thousand VM's and I'm trying to create a few scripts to quickly scan logs and I have figured out the majority of the presentation and wanted to know if there is an easy way using something like awk, printf, etc. which I know how to use but specifically to print an iterated range of values from the log files?

Example:

```
awk -F, '{printf $(1..5)}' huge_log_file.csv
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
etc.
```

I know how to properly awk, format, separate etc the printed output but thought it would be nice if I could specify a range of fields I would like it to print.

I'll update my question if I figure out how to do it with the suggested similar questions and/or on my own.

Thanks!

EDIT: I know how to print $1 $2 $3 manually but didn't include it in my example

EDIT 2: I am also aware of how to count the number of fields with awk using NF for making the range dynamic later which is my long term goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Ranges that begin with the first field

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat input.csv
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
```

With GNU awk at least, we can print the first five (or other number) of fields like this:

```
$ awk -F, '{NF=5; print}' OFS=, input.csv
a,b,c,d,e
```

For those who value conciseness over clarity, we could equivalently write:

```
$ awk -F, '{NF=5;} 1' OFS=, input.csv
a,b,c,d,e
```

#### Dynamic resizing

To leave off the last 2 fields, regardless of how many fields precede those two:

```
$ awk -F, '{NF-=2; print}' OFS=, input.csv
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
```

#### Other ranges

To print starting and stopping with arbitrary fields, then a loop is needed:

```
$ awk -v first=3 -v last=6 -F, '{for (i=first;i<=last;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==last?ORS:OFS)}' OFS=, input.csv
c,d,e,f
```

To print from the third field and dynamically leaving off the last two fields:

```
$ awk -v first=3 -F, '{last=NF-2; for (i=first;i<=last;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==last?ORS:OFS)}' OFS=, input.csv
c,d,e,f,g,h
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick point; `awk` is a lot more flexible, but if all you want is a particular range of fields, use `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f1-5 huge_log_file.csv
```

This is much simpler than an `awk` loop if that's all you need.

Comment: I had considered this idea also but there are at least 4 or 5 different log formats I'll be using as the input. Using the answers from John1024 I should be able to modify my script to use these different log formats, drop the columns I don't need, convert proprietary strings into 'management friendly' text with sed, etc.